# Difference between textColor and android:textColor

Tags: android

I'm sorry if my question looks beginner, but what's the difference between `textColor` and `android:textColor`? I can't understand where use which
Thanks for your help

Comment: Could you please give some context on where you are trying to decide how to make this decision?  Have you tried things that do or don't work the way you expect?

Comment: I'm using appcompat library and noticed that some attributes use without android namespace but the names are same, and now need to know the differences

Comment: Could you provide specific examples?

Comment: Something like the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`textColor` is an attribute provided in AppCompat library, where as `android:textColor` is provided in Material theme.

Example:

Using Material theme and referring `android:textColor` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    ....
    ....
</style>
```

using AppCompat library with only `textColor` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    ...
    ...

</style>
```

Comment: but still some appcompat themes uses android attrs, why is that?

Comment: because it is backward compatible. So you should use appcompat.

Comment: So how do I know which one I should use?

Comment: Read it here: https://chris.banes.me/2014/10/17/appcompat-v21/ http://developer.android.com/training/material/compatibility.html http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html

Comment: @Eclipse, just go through any of the above links(3).