# I'm having problems with "textColor" in my style.xml

Tags: android, android-styles

That's my style.xml and the error I'm getting after adding textColor item

[View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/h1EHG3V)

Another weird things is that "textColor isn't available as u can see in the next image.

[View post on imgur.com](//imgur.com/qgzvFhv)

and it doesn't matter if I pick any of those hint i get the same error.

What could be wrong?

Comment: how about android:textColor ?

Comment: i just had to add android:

Comment: <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>

Comment: but why do i have to add android: for the text color and no for the others attributes

Comment: i maybe because you only targeting below api 21.

Comment: oops.. I was wrong. Please read my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with this

```
android:textColor
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 1):

`textColor` is an attribute provided in AppCompat library, where as `android:textColor` is provided in Material theme.

Example:

Using Material theme and referring `android:textColor` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    ....
    ....
</style>
```

using AppCompat library with only `textColor` attribute:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="textColor">@color/blue</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

    ...
    ...

</style>
```

this answer credit to @rohitarya: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36378905/4758255